# AngularJS2 ng2-idle

Tags: angular

Just wondering if anyone has managed to get ng2-idle working with AngularJS2?  Implementing it in AngularJS1 was a breeze, but such a headache in AngularJS2.

Can someone see where I am going wrong?  I'm using angularJS2 via Visual Studio 2015.

I installed ng2-idle via NPM:

```
npm install --save @ng-idle/core @ng-idle/keepalive
```

Installer added necessary files to my package.json file (@ng-idle/core & @ng-idle/keepalive):

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "ag-grid": "^6.2.x",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "^6.2.x",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "^1.1.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0-beta.rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^1.8.3",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.32"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I then add these into my application via the system.config.js file:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
      'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid',
      'ag-grid-enterprise': 'node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise',
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js',
      'angular2-cool-storage': 'npm:angular2-cool-storage',
      'underscore': 'npm:underscore',
      'moment': 'npm:moment',
      'ng2-bootstrap': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap',
      '@ng-idle/core': 'npm:@ng-idle/core',
      '@ng-idle/keepalive': 'npm:@ng-idle/keepalive',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: { main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      lib: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'ag-grid-ng2': { defaultExtension: "js" },
      'ag-grid': { defaultExtension: "js" },
      'angular2-cool-storage': { main: './cool-storage.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'underscore': { main: './underscore.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'moment': { main: './moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'ng2-bootstrap': { main: './ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      '@ng-idle/core': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      '@ng-idle/keepalive': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      map: {
          'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
          'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Everything perfect until now.  App runs fine, no errors.  Now I try to inject the ng2-idle code into my app.module.ts file, using the NgIdleModule.forRoot() call:

```
import { NgModule, Directive, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Page1Component } from './components/page1.component';
import { Page2Component } from './components/page2.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/pagenotfound.component';
import { MainPageComponent } from './components/mainpage.component';
import { QuickReturnComponent } from './components/quickreturn.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import { Configuration } from './shared/app.configuration';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { CoolStorageModule } from 'angular2-cool-storage';

import { CollapseModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { NgIdleModule } from '@ng-idle/core'

@Directive({
    selector: '[layout]'
})
export class LayoutDirective {
    @Input() layout: string;
    @HostBinding('style.display') display = 'flex';

    @HostBinding('style.flex-direction')
    get direction() {
        return (this.layout === 'column') ? 'column' : 'row';
    }
}
@Directive({
    selector: '[flex]'
})
export class FlexDirective {
    @Input() shrink: number = 1;
    @Input() grow: number = 1;
    @Input() flex: string;

    @HostBinding('style.flex')
    get style() {
        return `${this.grow} ${this.shrink} ${this.flex === '' ? '0' : this.flex}%`;
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, FormsModule, AgGridModule.withNg2ComponentSupport(), AppRoutingModule, MaterialModule.forRoot(), CoolStorageModule, CollapseModule, NgIdleModule.forRoot() ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, FlexDirective, LayoutDirective, Page1Component, Page2Component, PageNotFoundComponent, MainPageComponent, QuickReturnComponent ],
    providers: [Configuration, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I run the app and I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost/angularjs_2/node_modules/@ng-idle/core/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?  I am following the code example on GIT line by line.  But I can't get past here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: after fixing above issue i am getting below error
getting below error :
Error: (SystemJS) ctorParameters.map is not a function
 TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
     at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (http://localhost:65321/assets/js/angular2/core.umd.js:1780:49)
If any 1 can help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue :)  Thought I would post the answer up here, in case anyone else has the same issue.

I changed my systemjs.config.js file to this and it all started worked :)

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
      'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid',
      'ag-grid-enterprise': 'node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise',
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js',
      'angular2-cool-storage': 'npm:angular2-cool-storage',
      'underscore': 'npm:underscore',
      'moment': 'npm:moment',
      'ng2-bootstrap': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap',
      '@ng-idle/core': 'npm:@ng-idle/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@ng-idle/keepalive': 'npm:@ng-idle/keepalive/bundles/keepalive.umd.js',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: { main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      lib: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'ag-grid-ng2': { defaultExtension: "js" },
      'ag-grid': { defaultExtension: "js" },
      'angular2-cool-storage': { main: './cool-storage.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'underscore': { main: './underscore.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'moment': { main: './moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'ng2-bootstrap': { main: './ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      //'@ng-idle/core': { main: './idle.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      //'@ng-idle/keepalive': { main: './keepalive.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      map: {
          'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
          'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: It would be easier if you highlighted what you changed rather than posting a lengthy configuration.  You have changed System loader configuration map to point to the umd js files and also have commented out the default extension as now you have provided valid extensions.